# using timer inside threads to prevent hanging code

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

My program create a bunch of threads and each thread connect to a website to retrieve some data (using mechanize browser).
Well, sometimes the internet drops when I'm reading the data and then the program hangs indefinitely:

```
response = br.open(url,timeout=30.0)
headers = response.info()
html = response.read() #the code hangs here
```

I've been reading around the net about the signal.alarm but it is not advisable to use in threads. 
My question is:  what other alternative I could use to handle this? threading.timer maybe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you improve the code to be a working example?